# Android - Set selection color for hyperlink text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have changed the text color of hyperlink text using android:textColorLink. Now 
I have to set another color when user click on it. I ahve tried with the following but no change.

```
android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

How can I set a selection color for a hyperlink text?Thanks in advance

Comment: read this [Git](https://gist.github.com/dafi/7657781)

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Thank to Squonk and alijandro

```
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link_tv);
        textView.setLinkTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(
                R.drawable.text_selector));
        textView.setLinksClickable(true);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        textView.setText("www.dummytext.com");
```

text_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff888888"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#ff888888"/>
    <item android:color="#ffffffff"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

This attribute android:textColorHighlight is used to define the color when you select text to cut or copy.
You can use a color selector and associate a state to yours.
Sample :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item color="@color/blue"
          android:state_activated="false"/>

    <item color="@color/red"
          android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

When your link is clicked set a flag for your state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setLinkTextColor` set to `ColorStateList` to get the effect in xml or java code.

link_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffff0000"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#ffff0000"/>
    <item android:color="#ff0000ff"/>

</selector>
```

Then in your java code

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_link);
textView.setLinkTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.link_color));
textView.setLinksClickable(true);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>"));
```

Comment: This changes the selection color when clicking on the text but the webpage is not opened. Anyway thanks it helped me to resolve the issue. answer is added below

Answer (score 1):

*color/link_color.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/primaryLightColor" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="@color/secondaryColor" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Asign into `TextView` with propierty `android:textColorLink="@color/link_color"`

**Sample**

[image]